# How to debug Perl projects

Tags: perl

In a Perl project,usually how to fix bugs in the script? 
Please can anyone give some idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first think is [perldoc perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)

I think it's the better place to start.

My second is : always put

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

on the top of your script, and you can put

```
use diagnostics;
```

too, for producing a more verbose warning diagnostics

---

Before opening the Pandora box, takes advantage of the Perl module `Data::Dumper`.

It's useful to display all (nested) data structures and objects, see (I use `perlconsole`, it's nice to try some tricks):

```
$ perlconsole
Perl Console 0.4
Perl> my $ref = { foo => 'bar', arr => [ 1, 2, 3, [ qw/a z e r t y/ ] ] }
HASH(0x1fc25a8)

Perl> use Data::Dumper;
Perl> print Dumper  $ref;
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 'bar',
          'arr' => [
                     1,
                     2,
                     3,
                     [
                       'a',
                       'z',
                       'e',
                       'r',
                       't',
                       'y'
                     ]
                   ]
        };
1

Perl>
```

---

You will see that Perl can run a script in a debugger with

```
perl -d -e 42 script.pl
```

help said :

```
$ perl --help | grep -- '-d'
  -d[:debugger]     run program under debugger
```

You can "trace" it too with :

```
perl -d:Trace script.pl
```

---

There's a [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) debugger too, it comes with `Devel::ptkdb` module, example :

```
perl -d:ptkdb script.pl
```

[image: ptkdb]

---

Try

```
perlcritic
```

too, a Command-line interface to critique Perl source.

---

Profiling your code is also possible, see

http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf

http://blog.timbunce.org/2008/07/15/nytprof-v2-a-major-advance-in-perl-profilers/

[image: debug]

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -c <your program>
```

...will give you any syntax errors in a Perl script, including specific error messages which you can look up on the Internet.

Also, give yourself a chance by placing:-

```
use strict;
```

At the top of each of your Perl files.  Without it, Perl will auto-vivify variables you mistype.  With it in place, any variable that hasn't been declared counts as a syntax error.

Comment: Using the term "autovivify variables" the way you've done is not entirely accurate. Auto-vivification can still happen with `use strict`, for example: `my $var; $var->{foo}->{bar} = 'this hash-in-hash has been auto-vivified'; print $var->{foo}->{bar}, "\n";`

Comment: Do you think he's doing anonymous hashes yet? :)

Comment: Not really. Just trying not to confuse him any more than necessary. Ok, maybe my comment didn't actually achieve that... ;)